# Insert text box into database

Tags: c#, sqlexception

I'm trying to have an insert button that takes values put into text box and them inserts them into a database. However the following error keeps coming up, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An explicit value for the identity column in table 'employees' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.'. I'm not sure on how to handle the syntax for this.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        int whoopsF = int.Parse(whoops.Text);
        String last = employeetxt.Text;
        String first = lasttxt.Text;
        String title = firsttxt.Text;
        String titleof = titletxt.Text;
        DateTime birth = DateTime.Parse(titleoftxt.Text);
        DateTime hire = DateTime.Parse(birthtxt.Text);
        String address = hiretxt.Text;
        String city = addresstxt.Text;
        String region = citytxt.Text;
        String postal = regiontxt.Text;
        String country = postaltxt.Text;
        String home = countrytxt.Text;
        String extenseion = hometxt.Text;
        String notes = phototxt.Text;
        int reports = int.Parse(notestxt.Text);
        String photopath = reportstxt.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into employees values('" + whoopsF + "','" + last + "','" + first + "','" + title + "','" + titleof + "','" + birth + "','" + hire + "','" + address + "','" + city + "','" + region + "','" + postal + "','" + country + "','" + home + "','" + extenseion + "', NULL, '" + notes + "','" + reports + "','" + photopath + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        display_employee();
    }
```

Here are the database variable types and what it looks like for the user when inputting data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkTY8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH2g0.png)

The textboxes are 1 off so ignore the names not matching the correct variable. Furthermore, one of the values will be Null whenever someone inserts something into it, the photos textbox.

Comment: Important side note: you're wide open to SQL injection. Use parameters instead of composed text from user input.

Comment: Imagine what would happen if someone entered `'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --` in one of those textboxes